# youtube api v3 CORS support in sencha touch 2

Tags: youtube-api, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, youtube-javascript-api

Using Sencha Touch, How do we query youtube v3 search api?
Below is the sample url which works fine when issued from a browser directly (NOTE: **Key is required**) : 
"https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&order=date&type=video&channelId=UC3djj8jS0370cu_ghKs_Ong&key=MY_KEY"

However the same url fails when loaded using sencha touch Store ajax proxy.
It seems that `OPTIONS` call is made against this URL and `GET` was aborted.

What is needed in Sencha touch store for working with youtube V3 google apis? I did not find jsonp support for youtube V3 api.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have used this api like this,

```
proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',
            useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
            extraParams: {
                part: 'snippet',
                q: 'ambarsariya',
                regionCode: 'IN',
                maxResults: 30,
                key: 'your_key'
            },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'items'
            }
        }
```

One more thing you have to do and thats is you have set a idProperty in the model of this store. Inside config of the model used I have used

```
idProperty: 'videoId',// its better if this name is not same as any fields name
        fields: [{
            name: 'snippet'
        }, {
            name: 'thumbnail',
            mapping: 'snippet.thumbnails.default.url'
        }, {
            name: 'title',
            mapping: 'snippet.title'
        }]
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thnx. `useDefaultXhrHeader: false` was missing in my case.

Answer (score 2):

It works well for me.

STORE:-

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.store.videos', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
        model: 'MyApp.model.Video',
        config: {
            autoLoad: true,
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',

                //This is required to enable cross-domain request
                useDefaultXhrHeader: false,
                url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search',

                extraParams: {
                    part: 'snippet',
                    q: "Enrique",  //Query string
                    regionCode: 'IN',
                    maxResults: 30,
                    key: 'AIzaSyD6FvoLaIFqyQGoEY4oV7TEWGAJSlDd1-8'
                }
            }
        }
    });

This is the model used by the above store.

MyApp.model.Video:-

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Video', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: [],

    config: {
        idProperty: 'videoId',
        fields: [{
            name: 'id'
        }, {
            name: 'videoId',
            mapping: 'id.videoId'
        }]
    }
});
```

It also works well for jsonp proxy also,

just change type: jsonp inside proxy and remove useDefaultXhrHeader config.